# Merge sort in C returns a list containing duplicates of the same 3-4 numbers. Other numbers are missing from sorted list

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, mergesort, function-definition

I'm trying to implement a basic merge sort program in C. However, I keep getting multiple instances of the same numbers in a row, where as other numbers are completely skipped. I used the following functions and main

```
void merge_sort(int *arr, int left, int right){
    if (left<right){
        int mid = left + (right-left)/2;

        merge_sort(arr, left, mid);
        merge_sort(arr, mid+1, right);

        merge(arr, left, mid, right);
    }
}

void merge(int *arr, int left, int mid, int right){
    int lenght1 = mid - left + 1;
    int lenght2 = right - mid;
    int left_arr[lenght1];
    int right_arr[lenght2];

    int i, j;
    for (i=0; i<lenght1; i++)
        left_arr[i] = arr[left+i];
    for (j=0; j<lenght2; j++)
         right_arr[j] = arr[mid + 1 + j];

    i=0;
    j=0;
    int k = left;
    while(i<lenght1 && j<lenght2){
        if (left_arr[i]<=right_arr[j]){ 
            arr[k] = left_arr[i]; 
            i++;
        }
        else{
            arr[k] = right_arr[j]; 
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }
    while (j<lenght2){
        arr[k] = right_arr[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void print_array(int array[], int length){
for (int i=0; i<length; i++)
    printf("%d ", array[i]);   
}

//MAIN FILE
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sorting.h"

#define ARR_LENGHT 8

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int arr[ARR_LENGHT];
    if (argc!=ARR_LENGHT+1)
        printf("Too many or too few arguments passed.");
    else{
        for (int i=1; i<=ARR_LENGHT; i++)
            arr[i-1]=strtod(argv[i], NULL);
        merge_sort(arr, 0, ARR_LENGHT-1);
        print_array(arr, ARR_LENGHT);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

example of input and output:
input: 6 5 4 3 2 1 8 9
output: 1 1 3 3 3 3 8 9

Comment: What happens in `merge()` if there is only one element?

Comment: @yourdad Why are you using strtod to assign the integer array?

Comment: You never compiled the code you shared with us (if you did you would have noticed missing sorting.h, merge defined after use).

Comment: This part at least has something weird going on: `int lenght1 = mid - left + 1; int lenght2 = right - mid;`
When left = 0 and right = 1 (**only one element**), mid is 0, so you have length1 = 1, length2 = 1, and you write **two** elements (one from left, one from right) overwriting the second element of your array.

Comment: The condition in `merge_sort()` is code smell.   Caller (i.e. itself) shouldn't call `merge_sort()`  if left>=right.  I would make it `assert(left < right);`

Comment: Okay, I know this doesn't break anything if it's consistent, but it's spelled "length", not "lenght". Aside from `print_array`, you used the misspelling repeatedly.

Comment: Merge is overly complicated.  As you create two temporary arrays of size `right - left` you might as well just merge into a single temporary of that size and `memcpy()` that into the `arr`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters it is unclear why you are using the standard function `strtod` that is designed to parse double values instead of for example `strtol` or even `atoi`.

As for the function definitions then apart from this while loop within the function `merge`

```
while (j<lenght2){
    arr[k] = right_arr[j];
    j++;
    k++;
}
```

you also need to add one more while loop

```
while (i<lenght1){
    arr[k] = left_arr[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}
```

That is you will have

```
while (j<lenght2){
    arr[k] = right_arr[j];
    j++;
    k++;
}

while (i<lenght1){
    arr[k] = left_arr[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}
```

The order of the while loops is unimportant.

Also the function `merge` should be declared before the function `merge_sort`.